# How to make a searchfield with option to select multiple choices

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need a search widget to select multiple choices and which can take model class ( Dropdown items of String). Also I need a callback function on the text change of the search.

A widget for searchfield which allows to take multiple choices

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_search_selection). By using this you can search and select multiple items based on your search.

Also, you can customize the model and pass your own model.

Here's an example from the official documentation:

```js
MultipleSearchSelection<Country>(
        items: countries, // List<Country>
        fieldToCheck: (c) {
          return c.name; // String
        },
        itemBuilder: (country) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 20.0,
                  horizontal: 12,
                ),
                child: Text(country.name),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        pickedItemBuilder: (country) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]!),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(country.name),
            ),
          );
        },
        onTapShowedItem: () {},
        onPickedChange: (items) {},
        onItemAdded: (item) {},
        onItemRemoved: (item) {},
        sortShowedItems: true,
        sortPickedItems: true,
        fuzzySearch: FuzzySearch.jaro,
        itemsVisibility: ShowedItemsVisibility.alwaysOn,
        title: Text(
          'Countries',
          style: kStyleDefault.copyWith(
            fontSize: 22,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        showSelectAllButton: true,
        searchItemTextContentPadding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        maximumShowItemsHeight: 200,
      )
```